# Django Rest Framework return True if relation exist

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two questions. How i can just return true if relation exist? For example I have post model and comment model also, comment have foreginKey to post. Now after post serialization i wanna have something like this

```
{
id: 2
content: "My first post!"
has-comments: True
}
```

And my second question is how rename field name in model relation? Again we have post and comment. In comment model i have foregin key to post like

```
post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

Now when i add new comment i send JSON data with {post: postIdHere}. Is possible to change post to postId only in drf not in django model?

I hope you understand me :)
Best Redgards,
Sierran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I can come up with is a custom `has_comments` field (rather than `has-comments`) with this in the serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class YourSerializer(Either Serializer or ModelSerializer...):
    has_comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    @staticmethod
    def get_has_comments(instance):
        # Choose whichever one works for you.
        # You did not specify some model names, so I am just making stuff up.
        return instance.post_set.exists()
        return Comment.objects.filter(post_id=instance.id).exists()
```

You may also have to specify the field in the serializer's `Meta` class. When first run, the framework will tell you exactly how.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! Only i get resposne for my second question and I can sleep peacefully :)

Comment: You can [override the `create()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) in your Comment's viewset. Pretty easy in the docs. Let me know if you run into any undocumented problems.

Comment: Then i can save postId to post but api would return still {post: 1} not postId.. i try use Charfield with source = post but then I lost possibility to select related post from dropdown.